# How can I get descriptive statistics of a NumPy array?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, scipy

I use the following code to create a numpy-ndarray. The file has 9 columns. I explicitly type each column:

```
dataset = np.genfromtxt("data.csv", delimiter=",",dtype=('|S1', float, float,float,float,float,float,float,int))
```

Now I would like to get some descriptive statistics for each column (min, max, stdev, mean, median, etc.). Shouldn't there be an easy way to do this?

I tried this:

```
from scipy import stats
stats.describe(dataset)
```

but this returns an error: `TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type`

How can I get descriptive statistics of the created NumPy array?

Comment: I think the error is because there are multiple `dtype`'s in your array. Especially a string would be problematic to describe statistically. Perhaps you could just loop over each of your columns, and describe the columns separately?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How can I just access, for instance, the second column of the array? I tried `stats.describe(dataset[2])` but it yields the same error as in my OP.

Comment: I suspect there is maybe something wrong with my array? How should a proper numpy-array based on a CSV file look like? mine looks like this, if I print it: http://pastebin.com/MYyqbSG0

Comment: Do you get the same error if you do `stats.describe(dataset[2].astype(float))`?

Comment: @beta If you are dealing with non-uniform data (looks like you are), you should have a look at `pandas` which is much more powerful for such kind of thing.

Comment: @M.T: Then I get `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'F'`

Comment: Use `unpack=True` in `genfromtxt` first

Comment: @Holt: I want to use numpy because I will use it in combination with `scikit-learn` and many examples are based on numpy... I dont think I deal with non-uniform data. I just have one column which is a string, because it's categorical data.

Comment: @M.T: Same with `unpack=True`

Comment: @beta Pandas' column are numpy arrays, so you can easily mix pandas and `scikit-learn`.

Comment: Look at `dataset.dtype`.  See the fields that you defined?  The field names?  That's how you access the columns.  You created a structured array. Read about those - either the docs or SO questions.

Comment: If no field names are given, the default field names are `'f0'`, `'f1'`, etc.  So instead of `stats.describe(dataset[2])`, use `stats.describe(dataset['f2'])`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is not a pretty solution, but it gets the job done. The problem is that by specifying multiple dtypes, you are essentially making a 1D-array of tuples (actually `np.void`), which cannot be described by stats as it includes multiple different types, incl. strings.

This could be resolved by either reading it in two rounds, or using pandas with [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

If you decide to stick to `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.genfromtxt('sample.txt', delimiter=",",unpack=True,usecols=range(1,9))
s = np.genfromtxt('sample.txt', delimiter=",",unpack=True,usecols=0,dtype='|S1')

from scipy import stats
for arr in a: #do not need the loop at this point, but looks prettier
    print(stats.describe(arr))
#Output per print:
DescribeResult(nobs=6, minmax=(0.34999999999999998, 0.70999999999999996), mean=0.54500000000000004, variance=0.016599999999999997, skewness=-0.3049304880932534, kurtosis=-0.9943046886340534)
```

Note that in this example the final array has `dtype` as `float`, not `int`, but can easily (if necessary) be converted to int using `arr.astype(int)`

Comment: This use of `usecols` is good.  I don't think you need `unpack`.

Comment: @hpaulj If one accesses the data the way you show in your answer (which I think deserves to be the accepted answer), then unpack is unnecessary. Still, in my experience, both with `genfromtxt` and `loadtxt` I find I always work with columns (ie. the transposed of the normal output) when dealing with scientific data from csv-like documents. It is also less easy to loop over the recarray fields.

Comment: I have opened a spin-off question for nested structures, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62385252/how-can-i-get-the-statistics-of-all-columns-including-those-with-a-nested-struct/62385253#62385253

Answer (score 63):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_describe = pd.DataFrame(dataset)
df_describe.describe()
```

please note that dataset is your np.array to describe.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_describe = pd.DataFrame('your np.array')
df_describe.describe()
```

Comment: I think this by far the easiest option. You don't even need to create a new variable, you just write `pd.DataFrame(my_array).describe()`.

Comment: For the case the OP asks for, I think the code of this answer should be `pd.read_csv("data.csv").describe()` rather than implying that the data is loaded on a numpy array in the first place

Comment: Just one line, no for loop nothing. This is the best answer.

Answer (score 7):

The question of how to deal with mixed data from `genfromtxt` comes up often.  People expect a 2d array, and instead get a 1d that they can't index by column.  That's because they get a structured array - with different dtype for each column.

All the examples in the `genfromtxt` doc show this:

```
>>> s = StringIO("1,1.3,abcde")
>>> data = np.genfromtxt(s, dtype=[('myint','i8'),('myfloat','f8'),
... ('mystring','S5')], delimiter=",")
>>> data
array((1, 1.3, 'abcde'),
      dtype=[('myint', '<i8'), ('myfloat', '<f8'), ('mystring', '|S5')])
```

But let me demonstrate how to access this kind of data

```
In [361]: txt=b"""A, 1,2,3
     ...: B,4,5,6
     ...: """
In [362]: data=np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),delimiter=',',dtype=('S1,int,float,int'))
In [363]: data
Out[363]: 
array([(b'A', 1, 2.0, 3), (b'B', 4, 5.0, 6)], 
      dtype=[('f0', 'S1'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<f8'), ('f3', '<i4')])
```

So my array has 2 records (check the shape), which are displayed as tuples in a list.

You access `fields` by name, not by column number (do I need to add a structured array documentation link?)

```
In [364]: data['f0']
Out[364]: 
array([b'A', b'B'], 
      dtype='|S1')
In [365]: data['f1']
Out[365]: array([1, 4])
```

In a case like this might be more useful if I choose a `dtype` with 'subarrays'.  This a more advanced dtype topic

```
In [367]: data=np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),delimiter=',',dtype=('S1,(3)float'))
In [368]: data
Out[368]: 
array([(b'A', [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]), (b'B', [4.0, 5.0, 6.0])], 
      dtype=[('f0', 'S1'), ('f1', '<f8', (3,))])
In [369]: data['f1']
Out[369]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  6.]])
```

The character column is still  loaded as `S1`, but the numbers are now in a 3 column array.  Note that they are all float (or int).

```
In [371]: from scipy import stats
In [372]: stats.describe(data['f1'])
Out[372]: DescribeResult(nobs=2, 
   minmax=(array([ 1.,  2.,  3.]), array([ 4.,  5.,  6.])),
   mean=array([ 2.5,  3.5,  4.5]), 
   variance=array([ 4.5,  4.5,  4.5]), 
   skewness=array([ 0.,  0.,  0.]), 
   kurtosis=array([-2., -2., -2.]))
```

Answer (score 3):

Official Scipy Documentation [Example](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.describe.html)

```
#INPUT
from scipy import stats
a = np.arange(10)
stats.describe(a)

#OUTPUT
DescribeResult(nobs=10, minmax=(0, 9), mean=4.5, variance=9.166666666666666,
               skewness=0.0, kurtosis=-1.2242424242424244)

#INPUT
b = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
stats.describe(b)

#OUTPUT
DescribeResult(nobs=2, minmax=(array([1, 2]), array([3, 4])),
               mean=array([2., 3.]), variance=array([2., 2.]),
               skewness=array([0., 0.]), kurtosis=array([-2., -2.]))
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who need **fast computations**, scipy + numpy are faster than pandas:

```py
# scipy + numpy
def get_stats(v):
    res = stats.describe(v)
    return np.concatenate([
        [
            res.minmax[0],
            res.minmax[1],
            res.mean,
            res.variance,
            res.skewness,
            res.kurtosis
        ],
        np.percentile(v, q=[10, 25, 50, 75, 90])
    ])
```

```py
%timeit get_stats(np.arange(100))
639 µs ± 11.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

%timeit pd.Series(np.arange(100)).describe(percentiles=[0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.9])
830 µs ± 31.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

Plus in the [`describe()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html) pandas does not extract *kurtosis* and *skewness*

---

**Warning**: using `pd.DataFrame(array).describe()` is slower:

```py
%timeit pd.DataFrame(np.arange(100)).describe(percentiles=[0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.9])
1.43 ms ± 75.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```